# Not sure how to make a loading screen disappear?

Tags: html, css

I've recently been working on a project which involves a heavyloaded webpage,
it loads the files in the background and then eventually will allow them to disappear after a certain amount of time,

I have tried my hardest to do some research but with many attempts I have not come to a usable conclusion. I'd love it if you could possibly help out,
I will probably edit my code later but for now im just using that codepen.io overused loading square, for your information. 
If you can help, it'll be greatly appreciated, Here's my code.

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>html { overflow-y: hidden; }</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        s$("div.formSentMsg").delay(3200).fadeOut(300) 
    </script>


    <div><center><i><p>Loading</p></i></center></div>



  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Loading Square</title>



  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div><span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span></div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Css**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #edae38;
}
.loader {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        position: relative;
        border: 8px solid #3a3b3d;
        animation: loader 4s infinite ease;
        align-self: center;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #3a3b3d;



}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3a3b3d;
  animation: loader-inner 4s infinite ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #3a3b3d;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  75% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
 p {
    font-family: 'bignoodletitling';
    top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 200px;
    color: #3a3b3d;
    font-size: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #3a3b3d;
    }
```

**I understand,**

As probably one of you it might be extremely easy for you to achieve this but when i receive your inputit's greatly appreciated and it helps me learn for future references,
Thanks. - David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the element that contains the loading stuff once all of your assets have loaded. I gave the loading element an ID (`#loadingEl`) and am using jQuery to remove it on `$(window).on('load'...`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #edae38;
}

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  border: 8px solid #3a3b3d;
  animation: loader 4s infinite ease;
  align-self: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #3a3b3d;
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3a3b3d;
  animation: loader-inner 4s infinite ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #3a3b3d;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

p {
  font-family: 'bignoodletitling';
  top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  color: #3a3b3d;
  font-size: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #3a3b3d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    html { overflow-y: hidden; }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("div.formSentMsg").delay(3200).fadeOut(300);
  </script>


  <div>
    <center><i><p>Loading</p></i></center>
  </div>


  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Loading Square</title>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loadingEl"><span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(window).on('load',function() {
      $('#loadingEl').remove();
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi there Michael, Thanks for your assistance. What my code does is just download recourses (images) in the background and then they disappear after a few seconds once they've fully loaded. Im not exactly certain on how im meant to add the script to my code, if you could assist me or give me a further tip it'd be greatful. Thanks, (The background is included in this so thats what im slightly unsure about also)

Comment: @BeastFox Your loading elements are in a `<div>` right now. I changed that to `<div id="loadingEl">`. Once your assets are done downloading and you're ready to remove the loading stuff, run this `$('#loadingEl').remove();`

Comment: Thanks @Michael-Coker, would there be a way to add an element of time to this? for example after 7 seconds the `$('#loadingEl').remove()` would disappear automatically? If not, i'll try my best to work it out, but thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: @BeastFox Yeah `setTimeout(function() { $('#loadingEl').remove(); },7000);` but if you're just waiting 7 seconds, that's really poor practice. What if the site finishes before then, or is still loading stuff for people after 7 seconds? That creates a really poor experience for the user. And keep in mind that however long the site takes to load for you isn't the same as it will take for someone else. Odds of the site finishing loading at 7 seconds for everyone is really low.

Comment: I understand, but thank you a lot for helping out. It's not a massive file but it should be more than enough time to load most elements, if not then I will be able to add some more code or come back to SOF if I need more assistance. Anyway thanks for helping me!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to make a post about how to intelligently make a script that monitors your files loading, and gives an indication when they're done. If it's just a bunch of images, that's fairly easy.